# multiple - same name radio

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm starting to make a little quiz page, where there are 3 choices opportunities. I here by to find out about what it is right,

Html

```
<p><input type="radio" name="svar[1]"><?php echo $svar1;?></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="svar[2]"><?php echo $svar2;?></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="svar[3]"><?php echo $svar3;?></p>
```

Php

```
 if($_POST["svar"][1] == $ok)
{
    $_POST["rigtigok"] = 1;
}
elseif($_POST["svar"][2] == $ok)
{
    $_POST["rigtigok"] = 1;
}
elseif($_POST["svar"][3] == $ok)
{
    $_POST["rigtigok"] = 1;
}
```

what I would like it / it must be outward is **$ok** is true with what comes from the database

if it shows like this:

```
$_POST["svar"][3] == $ok
```

then it will at the same time the **$ok** = 3

then it will also say that the content fits with what is being clicked by radio contents.

My Content from the database looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<?php
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, title, svar1, svar2, svar3, ok FROM quiz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')) { 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $svar1, $svar2, $svar3, $ok);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo $title;?></h3>
    <div style="padding:5px 10px;">
        <p><input type="radio" name="svar[1]"><?php echo $svar1;?></p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="svar[2]"><?php echo $svar2;?></p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="svar[3]"><?php echo $svar3;?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["ok"]))
        {
if($_POST["svar"][1] == $ok)
{
    $_POST["rigtigok"] = 1;
}
elseif($_POST["svar"][2] == $ok)
{
    $_POST["rigtigok"] = 1;
}
elseif($_POST["svar"][3] == $ok)
{
    $_POST["rigtigok"] = 1;
}
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
}
?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="Nyt Spørgsmål" class="new upload_boxxen">
</form>
<?php
echo print_r($_POST["svar"]);
if(isset($_POST["ok"]))
{
    if($_POST["rigtigok"] == 1)
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

EDIT

How it is that I do not get anything out of **$_POST["rigtigok"]** to be the first me later that I can give my 3 points for his correct answer?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @kingkero sorry - my question go out on how it is that I do not get anything out of $ _POST ["rigtigok"] to be the first me later that I can give my 3 points for his correct answer.

Comment: Where are your `<form>` tags and submit button? Where is the posted input named "ok"? Where are the values of the radio button inputs?

Comment: @showdev i have add its now :)